# TYPO3 on Debian: Error after Install Tool "class.t3lib_flashmessage.php"

Tags: debian, typo3

I tried to run a TYPO3 on my Debian server.

Now i get this error message, after i ran through the install tool and the `1-2-3 Wizard`.

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vipkaisers/t3lib/class.t3lib_flashmessage.php' (include_path='/var/www/vipkaisers/typo3/contrib/pear/:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/typo3/versions/typo3_src-4.5/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php on line 5063

Can someone help? Are more information needed?

Regards,
Max

Answer (score 0):

Problem not solved, but i reinstalled my debian server and configured the apache2 and others by hand. I think that my problems came from a misconfigured server setting.

Regards,
Max